# Check if server is dead - external image loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to load lots of external images. But sometimes one of these external servers are down.

What can I do? I want to put an error image over the image that can't be loaded.

I have tried with JQuery `onError`, but NO result because these images don't have errors but they only stay loading.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file exists before linking to it, and then, if not, load an alternative image. There is a workaround needed to check remote files existence.  This function should help you out.

```
function fileExists($path){
    return (@fopen($path,"r")==true);
}
```

then call your images this way

```
(fileExists($path) == true ? $originalimagepath : $errorimagepath)
```